# config parser duplicate section python2 vs python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Let assume that ini file has duplicate section.

If I use with ConfigParser for python2.7 then I don't get an exception and it reads the latest values and does a merge with previous options.
If I use with configparser for python3, in my case python3.5.1a, then the default behavior throw duplicate exception if strict=True.

My questions are:

1.Is python2.7 have a bug ? I excepted to get exception.

2."Reads the latest values and does a merge with previous options" is it correct behavior or not ?

Comment: [DuplicateSectionError](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.DuplicateSectionError) is listed in the official docs for Python27's configparser module which appears to be raised exactly in the case you would expect. How exactly did you use configparser and what does your ini file look like to make py27 ignore duplicate section names?

Comment: yes. ConfigParser of py2.7 ignore duplicates and do merge. This that I want.  @shmee